# OptaPlanner: how to get current intermediate result during planning

Tags: optaplanner

I noticed in the optaplanner examples, specifically the nurse rostering example, the GUI updates with the current best solution found.

I'd like to mimic something like this in my app but I'm unsure how I can get the current best solution after calling, for example `solver.solve(roster);`

Furthermore how would I be able to even update something on, let's say, a GUI if I'm "stuck" in the solver() method while solving.

I'm looking for some basic direction on where to start because I cannot find anything in the user guide, but I might just be blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at **listing to new best solution events** in the manual.